# Is there a way to "stabilize" past built unstable Gentoo binary packages without rebuilding?

Tags: package-management, gentoo, binary, packaging

Here's the scenario:

- build some ~amd64 package versions on your binhost
- later those same package versions go stable in portage, so no version bumps involved
- even if packages are listed stable in portage, binhost clients still see binpkg metadata saying package is ~amd64

I want to avoid rebuilding whole packages basically just to toggle the stability keyword. Looking for some script, tool, oneliner that can take care of the whole package database in cron runs or manually.

Answer (score 0):

All information about installed packages is kept under /var/db/pkg tree. If you edit the info there (such as `USE`, `KEYWORDS` and possibly the preserved ebuild) the package manager will be tricked into thinking that stable package was installed (or different `USE` flags used). You can even move the package subdirectories around there to emulate portage tree layout changes (like the relatively recent changes to Qt components classification).

Comment: Right, that's pretty much what I have been manually doing right now. Then `quickpkg <package>`.

I wonder if this is indeed the most optimal way. If unpacking-changing-repacking metadata sitting inside binpkg is any less processing?

Either way, makes sense to always update the /var/db/pkg tree, too.

Comment: My experience with binpkg indicates that they are rarely worth the trouble (portage always invents plenty of reasons not to select the available binary packages even before any tweaking takes place). These days I find it more convenient to actually write new *-bin ebuilds for whatever binary tarballs I need to keep around - with EAPI-5 those are only 3-4 lines.

Comment: That's an interesting approach, although I can't say I'm sharing your experience. I'm basically running my own distribution here for in-house machines.. it doesn't feel like custom-ebuilding everything is feasible. Why not Sabayon then in the first place?