# How to allow unstable while preferring stable packages in gentoo?

Tags: gentoo, portage

Building on [my previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/314502/43610), I'd like a more automatic way of [allowing unstable packages](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/ACCEPT_KEYWORDS#Stable_and_unstable_keywords) when there is no stable version in the tree, but otherwise using stable versions.

My reading of the docs, reinforced by [this recent forum thread](https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-1043848-start-0-postdays-0-postorder-asc-highlight-.html), indicates that there is no way to do this. One must choose between all stable and all unstable, and then manually override each exception in `package.accept_keywords`.

This makes for a dilemma in keeping `package.accept_keywords` up-to-date:

- If an explicit version is keyworded, it cannot be automatically updated.
- If no explicit version is keyworded, it cannot be automatically unkeyworded should a version be stabilized in the future.

The latter is the more acceptable choice, but it still means I'm occasionally going through my `package.accept_keywords` and running `eshowkw` to see if it ended up getting stabilized.

Comment: Yep, manual `package.accept_keywords` management is where it's at + periodic `eix-test-obsolete` reporting. I'm also still interested in http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106301/is-there-a-way-to-stabilize-past-built-unstable-gentoo-binary-packages-without?rq=1 for my binhost, where you lead the way building unstable packages, but to avoid manual keyword management on client hosts, it would be terrific to automatically "stabilize" binpkgs after the build.

Comment: @lkraav Thanks for the info. It seems like `eix-test-obsolete` is really critical when you keyword explicit versions. I suppose it's still useful for identifying packages that are no longer required when not keywording explicit versions.

Comment: the only thing I haven't solved with `eix` yet is to find out what obsolete USE flags I have. It handles keywords really well though.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a script that checks for unnecessary keyworded atoms in `package.accept_keywords` and uploaded it, along with the rest of my [gentoo-scripts](https://github.com/ryneeverett/gentoo-scripts). To quote from the header comment in `gentoo-check-unstable-keywords`:

```
# This script reports unnecessary unstable keywords in
# /etc/portage/package.accept_keywords.
#
# A keyword is considered unnecessary when:
#     - The atom is not installed. OR
#     - A stable version of the atom is available which
#         - Is not masked by the user's /etc/portage/package.mask. AND
#         - Meets the requirements of any dependent atoms installed.
```

This resolves the second horn of the central dilemma of my question:

> - If no explicit version is keyworded, it cannot be automatically unkeyworded should a version be stabilized in the future.